# Apache reverse proxy: no protocol handler

Tags: apache-http-server, reverse-proxy

I am trying to configure a reverse proxy with apache, but I am getting a `No protocol handler was valid for the URL` error, which I do not understand.

This is the relevant configuration of apache:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass        /gonvaled/examples/jsonrpc/output/services/ http://localhost:8000/services/
ProxyPassReverse /gonvaled/examples/jsonrpc/output/services/ http://localhost:8000/services/
```

The requests is reaching apache as:

```
POST /gonvaled/examples/jsonrpc/output/services/EchoService.py HTTP/1.1
```

And they should be forwarded to my internal service, located at:

```
0.0.0.0:8000/services/EchoService.py
```

These are the logs:

```
==> /var/log/apache2/error.log <==
[Wed Jun 20 02:05:20 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1506): [client 127.0.0.1] proxy: http: found worker http://localhost:8000/services/ for http://localhost:8000/services/EchoService.py, referer: http://localhost/gonvaled/examples/jsonrpc/output/JSONRPCExample.safari.cache.html
[Wed Jun 20 02:05:20 2012] [debug] mod_proxy.c(998): Running scheme http handler (attempt 0)
[Wed Jun 20 02:05:20 2012] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /gonvaled/examples/jsonrpc/output/services/EchoService.py. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Wed Jun 20 02:05:20 2012] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 127.0.0.1] Zlib: Compressed 614 to 373 : URL /gonvaled/examples/jsonrpc/output/services/EchoService.py, referer: http://localhost/gonvaled/examples/jsonrpc/output/JSONRPCExample.safari.cache.html

==> /var/log/apache2/access.log <==
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jun/2012:02:05:20 +0200] "POST /gonvaled/examples/jsonrpc/output/services/EchoService.py HTTP/1.1" 500 598 "http://localhost/gonvaled/examples/jsonrpc/output/JSONRPCExample.safari.cache.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19"
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found the problem. The `proxy_http` module needs to be activated too in Apache (I had only `proxy_html` and `proxy`)

Answer (score 23):

For me, on apache `httpd 2.4`, this happened because i was missing the trailing slash:

**Did not work:**

```
    <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
        BalancerMember http://192.168.111.7
        BalancerMember http://192.168.111.80
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster
```

**Worked!**

```
    <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
        BalancerMember http://192.168.111.7
        BalancerMember http://192.168.111.80
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/
```

(added `/` at the end)

Comment: For me, apache 2.2.15, <kbd>/</kbd> at the end works. THX!

Comment: helped me on Apache/2.4.10 (Debian). This needs to be documented! The error message is extremely obtuse

Answer (score 2):

For those that come looking for answers, another possibility is the URL service name to backend too is missing. With LogLevel Debug, and mod_proxy and mod_proxy_fcgi, I was seeing the following:

`[debug] proxy: fgci: found worker fgci://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/.../index.php
[debug] mod_proxy.c(1026): Running scheme fgci handler (attempt 0)
[debug] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(800): [client ...] AH01076: url: fgci://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/.../index.php proxyname: (null) proxyport: 0
[debug] mod_proxy_fcgi.c(805): [client ...] AH01077: declining URL fgci://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/.../index.php
[warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /.../index.php. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.`

Thankfully the code for mod_proxy_fastcgi (I'm using a backport for Apache 2.2 on RHEL6) is available at https://github.com/ceph/mod-proxy-fcgi/blob/master/mod_proxy_fcgi.c#L805, which is this piece of code:

```
if (strncasecmp(url, "fcgi:", 5) != 0) {
    ap_log_rerror(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_DEBUG, 0, r, APLOGNO(01077) "declining URL %s", url);
    return DECLINED;
}
```

If you look closely at the logs -- I only noticed it when looking at the code that issues the message -- you'll see that what should be `fcgi://...` is misspelt as `fgci://...`

So when you see `declining URL` it means either:

- You don't have a handler loaded that accepts the service (eg. fcgi:), or
- you have misspelt the service name.

Comment: I upvoted because of the "When you see this error it means..." portion of this answer.  I feel that this should lead most searchers in the right direction.